# android_package_manager show permissions of other installed app

Tags: android, flutter

I want to show a list of permissions of all installed apps on android. This needs to be in a `ListTile`. I'm using the `android_package_manager` but this doesn't work. There are no error messages and I'm looking at apps that have permissions on my device.

```dart
List<String> permissionList = [];
final pm = AndroidPackageManager();
pm.getPackageInfo(packageName: package).then(
  (value) => {
     dir = value!.applicationInfo!.sourceDir!, 
     if (value.requestedPermissions != null) permissionList = value.requestedPermissions!
  },
);
```

```dart
ListTile(
  title: const Text('Permissions'),
  subtitle: ListView.builder(
    shrinkWrap: true,
    itemCount: permissionList.length,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
       return Text(permissionList[index]);
    },
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the `android_package_manager` it is better to do it with native Kotlin code.

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

for (ApplicationInfo applicationInfo : packages) {
   Log.d("test", "App: " + applicationInfo.name + " Package: " + applicationInfo.packageName);

   try {
      PackageInfo packageInfo = pm.getPackageInfo(applicationInfo.packageName, PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);

      //Get Permissions
      String[] requestedPermissions = packageInfo.requestedPermissions;

      if(requestedPermissions != null) {
         for (int i = 0; i < requestedPermissions.length; i++) {
            Log.d("test", requestedPermissions[i]);
         }
      }
   } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```